# Listar todos os dados de uma API em lista numérica (Array)

Tags: php, html, array, api

Tenho este Array:

```
[tracks] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Amiga Da Minha Mulher
                            [artist] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Seu Jorge
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Tá Vendo Aquela Lua
                            [artist] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Exaltasamba
                                )
                        )
```

A quantidade de números depois de `['data']` é o número de músicas, ou
seja, varia muito conforme a playlist. Coloquei só dois como
exemplo, mas no [link da API](https://api.deezer.com/playlist/4213387182) você pode ver exemplos com tudo.

Em `"tracks"` tem a lista de músicas + nome do artista de cada música.
Como listar elas assim:

01 - Amiga Da Minha Mulher - Seu Jorge

02 - Tá Vendo Aquela Lua - Exaltasamba

**E assim vai...**

Tento fazer de tudo, mas sempre dá erro.

Comment: Mas quer listar com php ou javascript ?

Comment: *"Tento fazer de tudo, mas sempre dá erro"* - Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código que tentou fazer e qual o erro que está dando

Comment: @Isac somente com php mesmo, pois vou colocar a lista em um formulário!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é

1. Fazer uma requisição a API usando cURL do PHP
2. Transformar o JSON em um Objeto
3. Filtrar os dados solicitados (no caso você quer o titulo da música e o autor)
4. Montar um HTML com esses dados usando `<ul><li></li></ul>`

**Observação: é apenas necessário colocar a URL da API na variável $urlAPI**

Código:

```
<?php

$urlAPI = 'URL_API';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    /**
     * Observação: coloque sempre a opção 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' como true, por questões de segurança.
     * Coloquei como false apenas para responder a resposta, pois precisava configurar o certificado na minha máquina.
     */
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $urlAPI
));

$dadosAPI = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$dadosAPI = json_decode($dadosAPI);
$dataTracks = $dadosAPI->tracks->data;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR"> 
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                counter-reset: section;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            li::before {
                counter-increment: section;
                content: counters(section,".") " ";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    </body>
    <script>
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        <?php
            foreach($dataTracks as $data)
            {
        ?>
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' - <?php echo $data->title; ?> - <?php echo $data->artist->name; ?>'));
                ul.appendChild(li);
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </script>
</html>
```